# How To upload Images/Files to Firebase storage in Java?

Tags: java, rest, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working in a functionality where i need to upload an Image/File to firebase storage using java and expose it as an API. I have already achieved this functionality in angular 4 typescript. But now i need this method as an Java Rest API, so that my peer can also consume the same method instead of writing a new one. So is there any API or methods to write the image to firebase storage ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried googling it but all i can find is firebase storage examples for Java SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                    .setCredentials(credential)
                    .setDatabaseUrl(projectUrl)
                    .setStorageBucket("YOUR BUCKET LINK")
                    .build();

    FirebaseApp fireApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.getInstance(fireApp);
            InputStream testFile = new FileInputStream("YOUR FILE PATH");
            String blobString = "NEW_FOLDER/" + "FILE_NAME.EXT";        

    storageClient.bucket().create(blobString, testFile , Bucket.BlobWriteOption.userProject("YOUR PROJECT ID"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can try this:

1. Create a class to expose it as a web service in your API:

```
import com.yourcompany.yourproject.services.FirebaseFileService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
public class ResourceController {
    @Autowired
    private FirebaseFileService firebaseFileService;
    
    @PostMapping("/api/v1/test")
    public ResponseEntity create(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            String fileName = firebaseFileService.saveTest(file);
            // do whatever you want with that
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //  throw internal error;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

2. Create a service to upload the image to firebase storage.

```
@Service
public class FirebaseFileService {

    private Storage storage;

    @EventListener
    public void init(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        try {
            ClassPathResource serviceAccount = new ClassPathResource("firebase.json");
            storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().
                    setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount.getInputStream())).
                    setProjectId("YOUR_PROJECT_ID").build().getService();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String saveTest(MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
        String imageName = generateFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("firebaseStorageDownloadTokens", imageName);
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("YOUR_BUCKET_NAME", imageName);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId)
                .setMetadata(map)
                .setContentType(file.getContentType())
                .build();
        storage.create(blobInfo, file.getInputStream());
        return imageName;
    }
    
    private String generateFileName(String originalFileName) {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "." + getExtension(originalFileName);
    }

    private String getExtension(String originalFileName) {
        return StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(originalFileName);
    }
}
```

Note you need to download Firebase config file and store it as "firebase.json" under the src/main/resources folder.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

Also you need to add the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Java project is running in a trusted environment (such as their development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions), they can use the Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Storage.

See the [Firebase Admin SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) on how to get started, and then the [Google Cloud Storage documentation for Java clients](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Bucket.html) for more. Specifically have a look at the [sample of uploading a file in Java](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-java):

> ```
> BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob_name");
> BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
> Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(UTF_8));
> ```

Comment: Thanks Frank !! Will take a look at it.

Comment: FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("xxxx.json");
  FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
      .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
      .build();
   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);         
I tried the below snippet to initalize firebase, but i am getting error as method undefined in  Builder().setCredentials.I used firebase-admin 6.5.0 dependency in maven. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
String blobString = DIR + fileIdWithExtension;
Blob blob = storageClient.bucket().create(blobString, file.getInputStream(), Bucket.BlobWriteOption.userProject(PROJECT_ID));
```

But keep in mind that you should initialize firebase. For example

```
   private FirebaseApp initFirebase() {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount;
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(fileUploadPath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new FileStorageException(ErrorMessage.FILE_NOT_FOUND + "firebaseConfig.json");
        }
        FirebaseOptions options;
        try {
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setStorageBucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new FailedToSetCredentialsException(ErrorMessage.COULD_NOT_SET_CREDENTIALS);
        }

        return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }
```