# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined.How to set enviroment variable at Java Spring on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, firebase, heroku, google-cloud-storage

I am using Firebase and Google Cloud Vision api and Cloud Storage with Java Spring. I create the value of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` via eclipse on my own computer. I am using heroku for host.
But I could not find how to set this enviroment variable on the server I hosted.

Here is the error

> Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

I tried passing credentials using code
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

But it is not working for me. Because The functions I use do not have a `setCredentials` function.
I think I should save this as an environment variable in the Heroku but I couldn't.

Comment: Heroku has settings where you can define environment variables. You can either do it through settings in Heroku Dashboard in your browser or using command lines. More here:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: We have already tried this, but when we enter the file location in the value section of heroku, it cannot find the file.Heroku say file doesnt exist.We want something like this:Variable ==>GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,Value ==> service-account-file.json.But heroku cant find the file.We tried like this "account-file-json." and github link but it doesnt work.
So our main problem is value wants json file but heroku can't find json file.

Comment: I tried this https://github.com/gerywahyunugraha/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack but it is not working.Heroku => java.io.IOException: Error reading credential file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value 'google-credentials.json': File does not exist.

Comment: In this article there is an answer posted by `Chrisjan` that suggest to use `.profile` file. May be that is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku

Comment: Do you have "account-file.json" under the src/main/resources folder. May be this configuration can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462800/5869384.